# How to add same column twice to table in different places?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My db tables are like that:

1. routes - table for routes, with columns:

   a. destination_id 
    b. departure_id
2. destinations - table for all the destinations, with columns: 
   a. destination_id 
    b. destination_name.

Because every destination is also departure point I use one table for both.

**Relation is as follows :** 
 1. routes.destination_id = destinations.destination_id,
 also
 2. routes.departure_id = destinations.destination_id

**The result I need is as described:**

If routes.destination_id = 3 and routes.departure_id = 5, I want to match each of them to the corresponds name in the destinations table, and to put in the result the correct column names, for departure I want to call it departure_city and same for destination. Right now I get the same name for both different ids, so if destination_id #3 is New York and destination_id #5 is Las Vegas, I will get both as New York and that is not what I need.

So far, my query looks like that:

```
SELECT routes.*, destinations.destination_name as 'departure_city', destinations.destination_name as 'destination_city'
FROM routes, destinations
WHERE routes.route_departure_id = destinations.destination_id
```

Before you are telling me to use JOIN, I have done it with JOIN but couldn't change the column name! Also, I always received all the table's columns and I do not know how to get only necessary columns with JOIN!

Right now my issues are that I can't get the value from destinations twice, once for the route_destination and one for the route_departure and show different values.

Comment: The query in this question already specifies a join operation of the two tables in the FROM clause, albeit, using the ancient "comma" syntax in place of the newer JOIN keyword. (We prefer to ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operation and use the JOIN keyword, but that doesn't really change the query.) We can assign an alias to an expression in the SELECT list to assign a name to the column in the resultset. We'd need one join operation to lookup the "departure" city, and a *second* join operation to lookup the "arrival" city.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for *two* joins:

```
SELECT r.*, 
       dep.destination_name as departure_city, 
       dest.destination_name as destination_city
FROM routes r JOIN
     destinations dep
     ON r.departure_id = dep.destination_id JOIN
     destinations dest
     ON r.destination_id = dest.destination_id;
```

Additional advice:

- Use table aliases.  They make the query easier to write and to read.
- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Do not use single quotes to define column aliases.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Use backticks if you are using a name that needs to be quoted (and then, change the name so backticks aren't necessary).

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast & wonderful respond! It works fantastic! I found out that I don't strongly understand well the logic of how SQL queries are implemented, and now I understand it much better, thanks to you! If you can recommend of any book I should read to sharpen my MySQL skills like a pro it will help me so much, I do not like it when I have lack of knowledge! Anyways thank you very much for sharing your rich experience!

Comment: @EliranLevi . . . I recommend the books that I write, of course.  However, I don't advertise them on Stack Overflow.  You can look elsewhere on the web, such as at Amazon.